# Relationship between sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am supposed to find relationships between pairs of sets (subset, superset, equal) and then justify our solution. However, I am unsure about two of the pairs.

1. A \ (B ∪ C),(A \ B) ∪ (A \ C)
2. A ∩ (B ∪ C),(A ∩ B) ∪ (B ∩ C)

In the first one, I managed to get:

A \ (B ∪ C) ⊆ (A \ B) ∩ (A \ C)

(A \ B) ∪ (A \ C) ⊆ A \ (B ∩ C)

In the second:

A ∩ (B ∪ C) ⊆ (A ∩ B) ∪ (A ∩ C)

(A ∩ B) ∪ (B ∩ C) ⊆ B ∩ (A ∪ C)

Did I make a mistake somewhere? The set pair right before that was: A × (B ∩ C),(A × B) ∩ (A × C) and so I could easily find that they were equal.
What mistake did I make somewhere in the other two that I couldn't find ANY relationship between those sets?

Answer (score 1):

In the first one, you might look for an inclusion relation between $(A \setminus B) ∩ (A \setminus C)$ and $(A \setminus B) ∪ (A \setminus C)$.  In the second one, if you can't find a relation, you might look for counterexamples.